# Change value of factors

Tags: r

```
vec <- c("AAA", "BBB", "CCC", "DDD", "EEE", "FFF", "GGG", "HHH")
    x <- data.frame(id = rep(1:4, each = 6),
                    abbr = c(rep(vec[1:2], each = 3), rep(vec[3:4], each = 3), 
                                  rep(vec[5:6], each = 3), rep(vec[7:8], each = 3)))
```

So:

```
x  id abbr
1   1  AAA
2   1  AAA
3   1  AAA
4   1  BBB
5   1  BBB
6   1  BBB
7   2  CCC
8   2  CCC
9   2  CCC
10  2  DDD
11  2  DDD
12  2  DDD
13  3  EEE
14  3  EEE
15  3  EEE
16  3  FFF
17  3  FFF
18  3  FFF
19  4  GGG
20  4  GGG
21  4  GGG
22  4  HHH
23  4  HHH
24  4  HHH
```

Now I want to change first value of `abbr` to "a" and second value of `abbr` to "b" for each id.

desired outcome should look like.

```
   id   abbr
1   1    a
2   1    a
3   1    a
4   1    b
5   1    b
6   1    b
7   2    a
8   2    a
9   2    a
10  2    b
11  2    b
12  2    b
13  3    a
14  3    a
15  3    a
16  3    b
17  3    b
18  3    b
19  4    a
20  4    a
21  4    a
22  4    b
23  4    b
24  4    b
```

Length for each id will vary as will also length for each abbr within each id. All I can be certain of is that there will only be two values for abbr in each id.

I have tried to solve this with a for loop where I iterate over each unique id, but my effort not even worth to display here :)

Answer (score 2):

One way to do it via `dplyr` package,

```
library(dplyr)
x %>% 
 group_by(id) %>% 
 mutate(abbr = factor(abbr, labels = c('a', 'b')))
```

Answer (score 0):

In base R, the following split-apply-combine will work:

```
do.call(rbind,lapply(split(x,x$id),function(x){x$abbr <- factor(x$abbr,labels=c("a","b"));x}))
```

In several lines:

```
split_x <- split(x,x$id)
apply_x <- lapply(split_x,function(x){
                  x$abbr <- factor(x$abbr,labels=c("a","b"));
                  x})
do.call(rbind,apply_x)
#     id abbr
#1.1   1    a
#1.2   1    a
#1.3   1    a
#1.4   1    b
#1.5   1    b
#1.6   1    b
#2.7   2    a
#2.8   2    a
#2.9   2    a
#2.10  2    b
#2.11  2    b
#2.12  2    b
#3.13  3    a
#3.14  3    a
#3.15  3    a
#3.16  3    b
#3.17  3    b
#3.18  3    b
#4.19  4    a
#4.20  4    a
#4.21  4    a
#4.22  4    b
#4.23  4    b
#4.24  4    b
```

Answer (score 0):

The following base R method uses modulus to convert the underlying values and then feeds these to `factor`. This works for your example and will work in situations where you have two factor levels for each group ID such that the factor levels are ordered in terms of group ID.

```
x$abbr <- factor(2-(as.integer(x$abbr) %% 2), labels=c("a", "b"))
x
   id abbr
1   1    a
2   1    a
3   1    a
4   1    b
5   1    b
6   1    b
7   2    a
8   2    a
9   2    a
10  2    b
11  2    b
12  2    b
13  3    a
14  3    a
15  3    a
16  3    b
17  3    b
18  3    b
19  4    a
20  4    a
21  4    a
22  4    b
23  4    b
24  4    b
```